# Git Hubflow Switch to another Branch

Tags: git, github, hubflow

We use git hubflow. Each tam member have his own feature branch. I need to switch from my branch to another one.

Let's decide I am working in **feature/branch_1**, and my colleguae in **feature/branch_2**.

branch_1 contains **parent_project** and **subprogect_1** folders

branch_2 contains **parent_project** and **subprogect_2** folders

How can I get replace all contents of my workcpace ?

when I run

```
$ git hf feature checkout branch_2
```

I get

```
Switched to branch 'feature/branch_2'
Your branch is behind 'feature/branch_1' by 24 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

I can pull, but my **subproject_1** is still here.

Is it possible to completely switch from one feture brunch to another without any dependencies between branches ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing due to your previous action. 
If you pull (which means merging), of course you will get all the commits on the other branch - which include the **subproject_1** folder.

Maybe a look at how branching works in Git could be useful - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

On another note, do you want to get some changes from feature branch 1 in feature branch 2, but not the ones which include subproject_1 folder? 
If yes, you can cherry pick the commits that you want, without pulling and merging the branches.

I think it would help to clarify if you explain what are your intentions, and how you plan to achieve this using Git.

** I wanted to just comment, but I do not have enough points. Hope this helps anyway.